# Finding rows in a Julia dataframe where substrings are NOT found

Tags: dataframe, filter, julia

I have a dataframe df1:

```
using DataFrames
df1 = DataFrame(col1=[1,62,13,24], col2=["ab","bc","cd","de"])
```

which returns:

[image]

and I want to extract rows in df1 that do NOT include the substrings "a" or "e" in column 2. I can isolate the rows that do contain these substrings using filter:

```
df2 = filter(r -> any(occursin.(["a", "e"], r.col2)), df1)
```

which returns:

[image: |Row|col1|col2| | 1 | ab | | 24 | de |]

but what I want is the rows that do NOT contain these substrings:

[image]

I think I'm missing something obvious from the [documentation](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/), but I can't find an easy way to do this. I tried to isolate the rows that do contain substrings, and removing them from the original dataframe, but this still feels clunky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `!` in front of `any` like this:

```
julia> filter(r -> !any(occursin.(["a", "e"], r.col2)), df1)
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ col1   col2
     │ Int64  String
─────┼───────────────
   1 │    62  bc
   2 │    13  cd
```